# Enviar json para webservice e retornar status

Tags: java, web-service

Galera estou fazendo um curso da Caelum 36 mas empaquei em dado momento que necessito fazer isso:

```
curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"valor":"39.9","titular":"Fulano"}' http://localhost:8080/fj36-webservi
ce/pagamento
```

Só que no terminal tá me voltando isso

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/8
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 257
Date: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 21:35:40 GMT
```

O que faço para funcionar? Não sei consigo tratar esse erro. Está na página 98 (p quem tem a apostila)

Erro que aparece no terminal:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@72f1de92; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Classe: PagamentoResource

```
package br.com.caelum.payfast.rest;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import br.com.caelum.payfast.modelo.Pagamento;
import br.com.caelum.payfast.modelo.Transacao;

@Path("/pagamento")
@Stateless
public class PagamentoResource {
    private Map<Integer, Pagamento> repositorio = new HashMap<>();
    private Integer idPagamento = 1;

    @POST
    @Consumes ({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response criarPagamento(Transacao transacao) throws URISyntaxException {
        Pagamento pagamento = new Pagamento();
        pagamento.setId(idPagamento++);
        pagamento.setValor(transacao.getValor());
        pagamento.comStatusCriado();

        repositorio.put(pagamento.getId(), pagamento);

        System.out.println("PAGAMENTO CRIADO " + pagamento);

        return Response.created(new URI("/pagamento/" + pagamento.getId()))
                .entity(pagamento)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                        .build();
    }

    public PagamentoResource() {
        Pagamento pagamento = new Pagamento();
        pagamento.setId(idPagamento++);
        pagamento.setValor(BigDecimal.TEN);
        pagamento.comStatusCriado();
        repositorio.put(pagamento.getId(), pagamento);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.applica}) // cuidado javax.ws.rs
    public Pagamento buscaPagamento(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return repositorio.get(id);
    }   

}
```

Classe: PagamentoService

```
package br.com.caelum.payfast.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class PagamentoService extends Application {

}
```

Classe: Transacao

```
package br.com.caelum.payfast.modelo;

import java.math.BigDecimal;


public class Transacao {

    private String numero;
    private String titular;
    private String data;
    private BigDecimal valor;

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public void setTitular(String titular) {
        this.titular = titular;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public String getTitular() {
        return titular;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Transacao [numero=" + numero + ", titular=" + titular + ", data=" + data + ", valor="
                + valor + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Posta a classe `Transacao` junto com a sua pergunta. Acredito que o problema possa estar no atributo `valor` que tá sendo passado como uma `String` para o recurso.

Comment: Pronto, incluí a classe Transacao. Dá uma sacada.

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema é originado pelo fato de você estar enviando uma `String` para um atributo que espera um `BigDecimal`, que no seu caso é o `valor`.

Onde você envia:

```
curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"valor":"39.9","titular":"Fulano"}' http://localhost:8080/fj36-webservice/pagamento
```

Note que o atributo `valor` está representado da seguinte forma: `"valor":"39.9"`, quando ele deveria ser: `"valor":39.9`, sem as aspas.

Dessa forma, a sua requisição deveria ser:

```
curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"valor":39.9,"titular":"Fulano"}' http://localhost:8080/fj36-webservice/pagamento
```

Comment: Dando msm erro.

Comment: O `@GET` da classe `PagamentoResource` está funcionando?